# Peak current of inrush limiting inductor?

Tags: circuit-analysis, current, inductance

I have this tricky question and I can't wrap my head around it.

There is this inductor to limit the inrush current that will be charging up a capacitor. I'm questioning the design of it, but I don't know how to calculate it.

The input voltage is 240 V AC (60 Hz), so probably the worst case is about 330 V peak when this thing is energized, and I want to treat it like a DC at that moment but I'm not good at math.

The second part is a series inductor of 1 mH and then a 22 uF capacitor that gets charged.

I know that at first the inductor will be much more limiting in the current when this thing is first energized, but at the same time the capacitor represents the highest load because it is completely discharged. Then the inductor (I imagine) will quickly lose its impedance, but at the same time the capacitor gets charged and draws less current.

The questionable thing is that this inductor is only rated for 330 mA. I can't figure out if this is more than enough or not enough. Is it pretty easy to calculate this (even an approximation will be great) or is this something that is better simulated?

[image: simplified schematic]

I had a feeling there was something wrong with this circuit. I drew a very much simplified schematic but just for reference let me include the actual thing:

[image: power supply]

Comment: Inductors are highly imperfect devices. Significantly, they exhibit wire resistance. Also, there will be an optimal external resistor to use (assuming you don't find a perfect fit with the inductor for this) as part of the design. Also, if you are using a transformer, you might consider inserting a resistor in the primary circuit, with a relay that eventually cuts out the resistor. The relay remains unpowered until the DC output voltage (assuming transformer and bridge rectifier plus filter capacitors, for example) reaches some design level. And yes, there is math to such a design.

Comment: Also, there are many current ratings for inductors: current at which they will heat up enough to lose 20% of inductance, temperature limit current and so on. So for a short period its very likely that the inductor can survive much more than 330mA. (I'm not telling you to ignore the ratings, but to pay attention to the scenarios and specs they apply to).

Comment: Hmm. Is this newly added schematic supposed to be a line-powered 330 VDC supply with current limiting using just these three parts? I guess I missed reading that detail, earlier. My mistake.

Comment: Can you calculate Zo and SRF? and thus peak current assuming you had a Triac with ZCS? or not with random phase turn on

Comment: That will cause a huge surge current if turned on at 330 Vp with an ESR of Cap? and DCR of L  so you must add current limiting power R in series

Comment: which part is hardest to understand from my answer?

Comment: Sorry I didn't provide enough detail.

Comment: @pgibbons - Hi, Thanks for adding the full schematic. The one thing that jumps out at me is that there is a resistor (not sure if its designator is R28 or R29) between "Phase" and the diode. It seems to be 100 ohms, 3 W if I'm reading the schematic correctly. That is very relevant and will likely affect all the answers :-(

Comment: @SamGibson Ok that is my bad then and yes 100 Ohm.
I asked someone what actually happens and they said the inductors sometimes physically break because they are too close to the edge of the board and get bumped around. So allegedly, electrically speaking everything is totally fine here. I still have my doubts and I like the 2 answers a lot.

Comment: PG your original question was very misleading. Why?  The air core must be adhered/protected with polyurethane on theedge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### TL;DR

Your initial question bears no resemblance to the actual design.  The soft-start on the feedback will greatly reduce the stress on the components.

### This is a transformer and optoisolated forward converter with negative feedback on a series low-side switching FET with a soft-start cap to limit the target voltage for a slower rise-time.  This C21 could be increased for more protection margin from the ~ 3ms time constant with more than the 1uF used,  but a 20W transient on a 3W cement WW resistor is possibly safe (assuming that was done with the 1mH Air Cores. [image]

I'm not going to waste any more time on this question as it was presented poorly before the schematic with false assumptions.

For the simple answer consider series reactance and the exponential curve, time constant, T=RC and T=L/R  with a step input and each part has some resistance (TBD)

What is T? then I max

I know that if a diode is say rated for 10Adc it's bulk resistance is less than the inverse of Imax or Rs <= 1/I or  R <= 0.1 ohms, as an estimate.

Thus 340Vp/ 0.1 ohms would be 3400 Amps. Ooops **L does not current-limit here.**

---

SRF (LC)   ~ 1 kHz
Zo (LC) ~ 7 ohms min @ SRF
Vin (60Hz) = 240 V rms & 340Vp
thus steady state impedance @ 60 Hz is dominated by diode bulk resistance and Xc(60Hz)

To limit SS current in L to 0.33A then add R = 240/0.33= 740 Ohms or reduce C and use an active PFC boost circuit. But always compute Pd in R and derate by up tp 50% and Imax by derated by at least 25% based on your Load R.

If you happened to turn on the switch at peak voltage what is the impedance for a UHF spectrum of an air gap power switch turning?  basically it's limited by the diode bulk resistance and ESR of the cap and DCR of L.

[image]

Above shows a 10A diode with an ideal L and C drawing 50A peak or over 20 kW for a few microseconds.

This is why I said unless you had a zero-crossing switch (ZCS) driving a Triac, your cap and switch would be severely over-stressed.

**Bottom line is you cannot do this without further limiting the current.**

With a ZCS switch it would look like this

[image]  T**he cap. would still not like it** (poof) with the 1 kVAR shown in plot as 1kW surge current, so even here **you need a current limiting power resistor.**

Even with a 1k resistor that is rated for 10W you get a large surge peak, so often in SMPS they use NTC ICL's with a timer bypass (opt.) to raise the cold resistance.

[image]

Comment: Anything doesn't make sense? Last one has a surge power of 91 Watts in 1k.

Comment: Thank you very much for this explanation. The inductor(s) are air-core I'm fairly certain. Apparently they fail from time to time, well your explanation makes a lot of sense. I'm not an electrical engineer but the person that designed this circuit has been known to make mistakes.

Comment: Worst case ESR of cap for 22 uF general purpose is 10 ohms and low ESR is 0.1 Ohms for electrolytic and lower for plastic film.  The DCR of two 1 mH inductors air core will be around 0.5 Ohms each (L/R=2000)   so the worst case surge Pmax is on the resistor but worst case temp rise will be on the capacitor if switched on at peak voltage.

Comment: It must also be low ESR film type to reduce heat rise and very large not electrolytic which will be the weak spot.  The diode is if it is a 1N4005 1kV 1A diode around < 0.5 ohms or less at huge currents but only rated for 1 cycle at 30A.  This would probably fail within a low number power cycles.  -1 for insufficient info on question.

Comment: Sorry that I wasted your time. I just thought that the inrush current when this is energized would exceed 330mA. I didn't consider the rest of the circuit because I figured it would only add to additional current draw in addition to the capacitor and that the cap would be responsible for the majority of inrush current. I knew there was series resistance all over but my thinking was that it is just about negligible when the input voltage is in excess of 330V. I might just try this out in real life and you probably won't hear back but if it fails I'll let you know.

Comment: You can also simulate in Falstad's if you know how to draw schematics and specify Beta for RsOn , I used Beta=40. It also has TL431. With lots of practise, that only takes 30 minutes, without... days

Answer (score 2):

The maximum current will depend upon where in the AC cycle the power is turned on.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f9dvHm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If the power switch is closed at the zero-crossing point of the AC cycle, or during the negative part of the cycle where the diode will not conduct, the current in the inductor will look something like this:

[image]

Of course it won't look exactly like this because components are not ideal. In fact, it may look a lot different from this because the inductor core, unless it is an air-core inductor, may saturate.

If on the other hand, the switch closes while the power is at the positive peak of the cycle, the simulated current looks like this:

[image]

The reality, again, will likely not look like this.

Comment: Agreed That's a big IF for zero crossing and not realistic.

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 who knows? The OP might use a zero crossing solid state relay. There are a range of possible outcomes. One possible outcome involves switching while voltage is zero or negative.

Comment: His inductor will still saturate and Pd may burn up and Cap explode even with ZCS

Comment: It's a tough call to say which would break first, the cap, the inductor or the diode on ZCS powerup.  The one with the highest resistance is my guess at peak current.  How big is a 1mH air core inductor?  Perhaps you should add some realism to put things into perspective

Comment: Thank you very much for this explanation. I heard that the inductors sometimes fail, it sparked my curiosity and I looked at the schematic but thought that was odd the way it was done or at least the inductors seemed weak.

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 Here is a 1mH air core inductor. Is it too bulky, heavy, or expensive for the OP's purposes? We don't know, because those purposes are neither contained in the question, nor in comments. So the OP can look at the weight, the bulk and the price tag, and make his/her own decision on the matter. "Jantzen Audio 1.0mH 18 AWG Air Core Inductor Crossover Coil" https://www.parts-express.com/Jantzen-1239-1.0mH-18-AWG-Air-Core-Inductor-255-250

Comment: @pgibbons I'm not sure I know what you are asking, or even if you are asking a question in that comment. Inductors can fail through damage to the insulation or the conductor. (Or even sometimes developing a crack in a core.) Saturation occurs when a non-air core inductor has so much magnetic flux ( think current through the wire time number of turns) that the inductance declines (eventually to that of an air core inductor with the same physical size). Saturation is temporary, but the overcurrent may result in excessive heat and consequent damage to insulation, wire, or less likely, the core.

Comment: @pgibbons You wouldn't use that speaker coil with 240V on your speakers so we assume since you indicated something like 240 mA max, you are using a ferrite core type with some resistance. When core saturates it turns in to a resistor probably 10 ohms and that would blow up with a cap at 0V if you were using a strong diode. otherwise the diode would blow up.

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 This only powers a microcontroller and it is fed from 240V mains. It is rare that this would be unplugged, mostly stays energized, maybe that's why these don't blow up. I'm there with you though, there is not enough current limiting for those weak components.